# How to stop a function after checkbox has been unchecked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am calling a JQuery function when the checkbox is checked but when I uncheck it, the function keeps on being triggered.

**Codes**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#check').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            drawLine();
        }
        else if (!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
          stop();
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea how I can stop the function?

Comment: does my answer was use full for you ?

Comment: Hi. No I could still draw the line after the checkbox was unchecked. But thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to copy  code snippet i've added and replace calling  `alert` to `drawLine` ?

Comment: Yes I did unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: strange, it's working in answer... could you double check whether you copied it correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

You **have to** listen to the change event and put function body into `if`.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="inputname"]').change(function() {
     // proceed only when checked
     if(this.checked) {
         // function body
     }
 });
```

To stop function if checkbox unchecked use code below:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="change"]').change(function() {
         // .........
         // some code prior verifying whether we need to continue
         // .........
         if(!this.checked) {
             return;
         }
     });
```

**Update**: according to your comments added working code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').change(function() { if(this.checked) { alert(1); } else if(!this.checked) { return; } }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="ho">
```

Comment: By function body you mean the whole function? Not just the function call?

Comment: code which are in your function or simply calling that function in case if `this.checked` is `True` .

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work: 
`$(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').change(function() {
                
                if(this.checked) {
                    drawLine();
                }
                else if(!this.checked)
                {
                    return;
                }
            });
        });`

Comment: does your input has name `check` ? verify that you use proper selector

Comment: Yes it has the name check. Even after unchecking the checkbox I can still draw the line.

Comment: @Damini Added working code snippet, `drawLine()` function replaced to  `alert(1)`